# Problem Binding a ObservableCollection to a ListBox in WPF/MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm working in some code , using wpf and starting to use mvvm. So far i have no problem, when i have one element and I have to show the values of it in the screen (binding of the specific name of the property). But now, i have to work with a property list , not knowing the names of it. So I created a class, named GClass, that only have two propierties, name and value. I created the ObservableCollection, and fill for now with direct values, and asign the view (lstview) datacontext with the object i have created. But I cant see any result, it always shows a blank listbox. Can someone tell me if see why is happening ?

Code of c#

```
         VDt = new ObservableCollection<GClass>();
        var vhDt = message.SelectSingleElement(typeof (Vh)) as Vehiculo;

        if(vhDt != null)
        {
            VDt.Add(new GClass() {Name = "Numero: ", Value =  ""});
            VDt.Add(new GClass() {Name = "Marca: ", Value = ""});
            VDt.Add(new GClass() {Name = "Conductor: ", Value = ""});

            lstview.DataContext = this;
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegionInIndex(RegionNames.MainRegion, lstview, 0);
```

Code of the view

```
 <ListBox Margin="5,5,5,25" ItemsSource="{Binding VDt}">
        <ListBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>                    
                <ListViewItem Content="{Binding Name}"></ListViewItem> 
               <ListViewItem Content="{Binding Value}"></ListViewItem>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListBox.Template>
    </ListBox>
```

I have research here, but i cant see, what I'm doing wrong. I will apreciate if someone help me.

Comment: are you seeing the populated listbox or no item?

Comment: I see a blank box, with no item or scrollbar at all, like you see the listbox in the design screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here:

Firstly, the `<ListBox.Template>` allows you to describe the template for how you wish to draw the listbox itself. What you are trying to do (seemingly) is render the items within the listbox, so you need the `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`

Secondly, within the ItemTemplate, you need to create, not a `<ControlTemplate>` but rather a `<DataTemplate>`

Last thing: Personally, I would use fit-for-purpose controls within my DataTemplates to render the views (e.g. `TextBlocks` instead of `ListViewItems`)

So your xaml should look something like:

```
<ListBox Margin="5,5,5,25" ItemsSource="{Binding VDt}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Hope this helps :)
Ian

Comment: Thanks!! It works perfect. 

I even see that you can take the <stackpanel>...</stackpanel> out, and substitute it with a <view: XXX> so you have a generic view container, and make the details in the specific view

Comment: Concerning text bindings in this form, it may be desirable to nest the textblocks to preserve proper text layout (wrapping, spacing, etc). Try this: <TextBlock><TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /><Run Text=" "/><TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" /></TextBlock>